# Iterate through release notes and count fixes per date

Tags: python, string, mutation

I hope you are well. I’m trying to find every instance of “Fix” in release notes, and grab the date (which is usually a line above).

For example (section of release notes):

```
Date:        : 2021-04-26
Comment:     : Fix wrong ...
```

I would want to grab the amount of “fix” occurrences and their corresponding date.

Example output:

```
Date: 2021-02-13
Fixes: 3
Date: 2021-01-18
Fixes: 1
Etc...
```

Here is what I’ve been trying:

```
WANTEDdate = 14
count = 0
dates = []
with open(file_name) as searchfile:

for line in searchfile:

    left,sep,right = line.partition('Date')

    if sep:

        count = count + 1

        temp = ((right[:WANTEDdate]))

        # temp = ((left[BEFORE:]))

        temp = temp.strip()

        temp = temp.strip(" :")

        if len(temp) > 0:

            print(temp)

            dates.append(temp)

        #print("Fix",count,temp)

        #print(temp)



# test
lookup = "Fix"
with open(file_name) as myFile:

for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):

    if lookup in line:

        dateLine = num - 1

        print("Found at line:", num)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `comment:` is only one line? Or split into multiple lines?

Comment: Hello, it’s one line

Comment: Ex: Date                                   : 2021-04-26T07:47:12-04:00

Comment                           : Fix wrong ifdef around logger constructor args

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file looks like this:

```
Date:        : 2021-04-26
Comment:     : Fix wrong 1

Date:        : 2021-04-26
Comment:     : ---

Date:        : 2021-04-26
Comment:     : Fix wrong 2

Date:        : 2021-04-27
Comment:     : Fix wrong 3
```

Then you can use `re` module to parse it:

```py
import re

with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    data = f_in.read()

dates = re.findall(r"Date.*:\s*(.*)", data)
comments = re.findall(r"Comment.*:\s*(.*)", data)

out = {}
for d, c in zip(dates, comments):
    if "fix" in c.lower():
        out.setdefault(d, 0)
        out[d] += 1

for k, v in out.items():
    print("Date:", k)
    print("Fixes:", v)
```

Prints:

```
Date: 2021-04-26
Fixes: 2
Date: 2021-04-27
Fixes: 1
```

Comment: What if I wanted to exclude the time? So it’s just 2021-03-24 and the amount of fixes

Comment: For example there are several fixes on one day but different times

Comment: @yishud You need then convert the date using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html) module and group by day, month and year. Or you can take first 10 characters out of the date string and group by this.